# C#: Merge sort with Vectors

Tags: c#, sorting, merge

I'm writing a program that needs to sort a list of houses based on their coordinates with the Euclidean Distance. To sort the list I use the merge sort algorithm.

Vector2 coordinates: are the coordinates of the buildings.
Vector2 house: is the coordinates of the main building.

Below is the class that does the merge sort:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;

namespace EntryPoint
{
public static class MergeSorter
{
    public static void DoMergeSort(this Vector2[] numbers)
    {
        var sortedNumbers = MergeSort(numbers);

        for (int i = 0; i < sortedNumbers.Length; i++)
        {
            numbers[i] = sortedNumbers[i];
        }
    }

    private static Vector2[] MergeSort(Vector2[] numbers)
    {
        if (numbers.Length <= 1)
        {
            return numbers;
        }

        var left = new List<Vector2>();
        var right = new List<Vector2>();

        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i % 2 > 0)
            {
                left.Add(numbers[i]);
            }
            else
            {
                right.Add(numbers[i]);
            }
        }

        left = MergeSort(left.ToArray()).ToList();
        right = MergeSort(right.ToArray()).ToList();

        return Merge(left, right);
    }

    private static Vector2[] Merge(List<Vector2> left, List<Vector2> right)
    {
        var result = new List<Vector2>();

        while (left.Count > 0 && right.Count > 0)
        {
            if (**left.First() <= right.First()**)
            {
                MoveValueToResult(left, result);
            }
            else
            {
                MoveValueToResult(right, result);
            }
        }
        while (left.Count > 0)
        {
            MoveValueToResult(left, result);
        }
        while (right.Count > 0)
        {
            MoveValueToResult(right, result);
        }
        return result.ToArray();
    }

    private static void MoveValueToResult(List<Vector2> list, List<Vector2> result)
    {
        result.Add(list.First());
        list.RemoveAt(0);
    }

    private static double GetEuclideanDistance(Vector2 coordinates, Vector2 house)
    {
        double distance = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow((house.X - coordinates.X), 2) + Math.Pow((house.Y - coordinates.Y), 2));
        return distance;
    }
}
```

}

On the line with the double asterisks: left.First() <= right.First(). There needs to come the GetEuclideanDistance() method, I think, but I don't get how?

I tried something like the following: GetEuclideanDistance( of the first item in left list) <= GetEuclideanDistance(of the first item in right list). But then I dont know what kind of parameters I need to give then.

Comment: Is there any reason you're not implementing a comparator and letting the core decide how to sort?

Comment: You want to sort them based on the distance to the main building, right? Then first you'll have to define the mainbuilding some how. `Vector2 main = new Vector2(some coordinates)`. Then you can compare: `if (GetEucledianDistance(left.First(), main) <= GetEucledianDistance(right.First(), main)) ... `

Comment: It is unclear what the sort key is here. Is it indeed (as the previous comments guesses) that all items are sorted according to their distance from a single location? If so, you'll need to pass that single location so that the `GetEuclideanDistance()` method can be called with that location. If not, then you need to explain what you _are_ trying to sort on. Without a good [mcve] it's impossible to know for sure what the intent is here, never mind how to help with your problem.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, what you want to achieve is `Collection` of `Vector2` coordinates sorted by their Euclidean Distance in relation to `house` coordinates.
If so, that should be sufficient:

```
//Coordinates - coordinates list to sort
//housePosition - position to which Euclidean distance should be calculated for every coordinate
private static List<Vector2> SortByDistance(IEnumerable<Vector2> coordinates, Vector2 housePosition)
{
    return coordinates.OrderBy(coordinate => GetEuclideanDistance(coordinate, housePosition)).ToList();
}


private static double GetEuclideanDistance(Vector2 coordinates, Vector2 house)
{
    double distance = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow((house.X - coordinates.X), 2) + Math.Pow((house.Y - coordinates.Y), 2));
    return distance;
}
```

Comment: +1 but it is likely that you guessed incorrectly. It is best to let such unclear questions pass and close them (as soon as you reach the rep to do that).

Comment: Because you are just comparing one distance relative to another, you could speed this up with a specialized function that left the square root part out.